# Qt Cannot queue arguments of type 'uint8_t' even with qRegisterMetaType

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to send a queued signal that uses a `uint8_t` as a parameter.

I get this error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'uint8_t'
(Make sure 'uint8_t' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

I have added `qRegisterMetaType<uint8_t>();` as the first line of `main()` and I also added `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(uint8_t)` to a header that every file includes.

I still get the same error. What's up with that? Is it some weird thing specifically with basic types, because it works fine for my custom classes.

Comment: Did you test it with some other primitive type like `uint16_t`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`uint8_t` is the `typedef` for `unsigned char`.
You can use Qt's `typedef` for unsigned char: `quint8` and you don't need to register it. Any class or struct that has a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor can be registered in `QMetaType`. Your `uint8_t` is atomic and you don't need to register it, just use proper `typedef` in Qt.
Anyway if you want to register that type so it can be used by `QMetaProperty`, or in `QueuedConnections` just make it right:

```
qRegisterMetaType<uint8_t>("uint8_t");
```

For more information how the `QtMeta` system work please read Qt's documentation for it: [doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html)